jinja2 evaluate variables in variable
Using Jinja2 v 3.0.  Say I have this context:
h = template.render(content=c, md=metadata)

Suppose my c, which is a string, also has variable in it, like {{ md.title }}, that I do want to be evaluated.
How can I do that?  is there a recursive kind of call to the jinja render method?

I found a not so secure way, but it does work if you "trust" your templates and the values they contain, which I do in my case.
We need to first compile the value c as a template, and then render that into a new string.  Then use this new string as the value in the final render.
Something like this:
# if c is the value we want to use and it contains things like
# {{ p.name }} variables that we need to replace, then

ct = env.from_string(c)
cv = ct.render(p=stuff)

h = template.render(content=cv, md=metadata)

